# Error Building ThingsBoard From Source - Thingsboard Server UI FAILURE

Tags: node.js, maven, thingsboard

I want to generate the Thingsboard dependency jars, which I want to use in my application to call Thingsboard API's from my java application.

To use Thingsboard dependency jars, I have to build the application as these jars not available in a public repository.

I am trying to build ThingsBoard application from source, I am following the instructions mentioned in
link - https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/building-from-source/

I clone the ThingsBoard report and then checked out "release-1.4" branch and ran the mvn clean install command.

The application build is failing with below mentioned error.

```
[INFO] Installing npm version 3.10.8
[INFO] Unpacking /var/root/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/npm/3.10.8/npm-3.10.8.tar.gz into /Users/admin/workspaces/IOT/ThingsBoard/source/thingsboard/ui/target/node/node_modules
[INFO] Installed npm locally.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:npm (npm install) @ ui ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install' in /Users/admin/workspaces/IOT/ThingsBoard/source/thingsboard/ui
[WARNING] npm WARN deprecated angular-ui-router@0.3.2: This npm package 'angular-ui-router' has been renamed to '@uirouter/angularjs'. Please update your package.json. See https://ui-router.github.io/blog/uirouter-scoped-packages/
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-fabiobiondi-angular-fullscreen-git-master-2346b489: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-fabiobiondi-angular-fullscreen-git-master-2346b489'...
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-fabiobiondi-angular-fullscreen-git-master-2346b489: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-fabiobiondi-angular-fullscreen-git-master-2346b489: github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Operation timed out
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-fabiobiondi-angular-fullscreen-git-master-2346b489: github.com[1: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Operation timed out
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/thingsboard/flot.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-thingsboard-flot-git-0-9-work-799e39f1: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-thingsboard-flot-git-0-9-work-799e39f1'...
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/thingsboard/flot.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-thingsboard-flot-git-0-9-work-799e39f1: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/thingsboard/flot.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-thingsboard-flot-git-0-9-work-799e39f1: github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Operation timed out
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/thingsboard/flot.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-thingsboard-flot-git-0-9-work-799e39f1: github.com[1: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Operation timed out
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/MichaelZinsmaier/CurvedLines.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-MichaelZinsmaier-CurvedLines-git-master-843e4689: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-MichaelZinsmaier-CurvedLines-git-master-843e4689'...
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/MichaelZinsmaier/CurvedLines.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-MichaelZinsmaier-CurvedLines-git-master-843e4689: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/MichaelZinsmaier/CurvedLines.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-MichaelZinsmaier-CurvedLines-git-master-843e4689: github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Operation timed out
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/MichaelZinsmaier/CurvedLines.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-MichaelZinsmaier-CurvedLines-git-master-843e4689: github.com[1: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Operation timed out
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/alenaksu/mdPickers.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-alenaksu-mdPickers-git-0-7-5-ca6ad268: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-alenaksu-mdPickers-git-0-7-5-ca6ad268'...
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/alenaksu/mdPickers.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-alenaksu-mdPickers-git-0-7-5-ca6ad268: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/alenaksu/mdPickers.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-alenaksu-mdPickers-git-0-7-5-ca6ad268: github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Operation timed out
[ERROR] npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/alenaksu/mdPickers.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-alenaksu-mdPickers-git-0-7-5-ca6ad268: github.com[1: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Operation timed out
[ERROR] npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
[ERROR] npm ERR! argv "/Users/admin/workspaces/IOT/ThingsBoard/source/thingsboard/ui/target/node/node" "/Users/admin/workspaces/IOT/ThingsBoard/source/thingsboard/ui/target/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install"
[ERROR] npm ERR! node v6.9.1
[ERROR] npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
[ERROR] npm ERR! code 128
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/fabiobiondi/angular-fullscreen.git /Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-fabiobiondi-angular-fullscreen-git-master-2346b489
[ERROR] npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/Users/admin/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-fabiobiondi-angular-fullscreen-git-master-2346b489'...
[ERROR] npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
[ERROR] npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=Operation timed out
[ERROR] npm ERR! github.com[1: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Operation timed out
---
---
[INFO] Thingsboard ........................................ SUCCESS [  1.895 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Commons ......................... SUCCESS [  0.070 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Common Data ..................... SUCCESS [  4.105 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Common Messages ................. SUCCESS [  0.716 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Common Transport components ..... SUCCESS [  0.739 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server DAO Layer ....................... SUCCESS [  8.202 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Extensions API .................. SUCCESS [  1.109 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Core Extensions ................. SUCCESS [  4.167 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Extensions ............................. SUCCESS [  0.054 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server RabbitMQ Extension .............. SUCCESS [  1.810 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server REST API Call Extension ......... SUCCESS [  0.704 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Kafka Extension ................. SUCCESS [  2.283 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server MQTT Extension .................. SUCCESS [  0.536 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server SQS Extension ................... SUCCESS [  3.292 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server SNS Extension ................... SUCCESS [  1.418 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Transport Modules ............... SUCCESS [  0.028 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard HTTP Transport ......................... SUCCESS [  0.511 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard COAP Transport ......................... SUCCESS [  1.111 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard MQTT Transport ......................... SUCCESS [  0.711 s]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server UI .............................. FAILURE [02:53 min]
[INFO] Thingsboard Server Tools ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ThingsBoard Server Application ..................... SKIPPED
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved issue in few steps

```
1. Restart System, so that it can close if in use.

 2. Open command prompt with admin previleges

 3. Run mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Make sure you have java 8 , maven 3.0 + & git installed.
if still issue is there then remove node/npm from system the repeat all the points.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logs you obviously had issues to connect to github.com. Maybe some temporary issues. Try to rebuild. If not - try to clean ui/node_modules folder and rebuild again.